# Azure ConnectionStrings feature not working with ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-postgresql

I am totally new to using Azure services. I've been trying to deploy a C# / ASP.NET Core 7 app I created that relies on Postgres as the database and Entity Framework as ORM.

I used App Services (Linux) to deploy my app from a GitHub Action and the Postgres flexible server as the database.

However my app is unable to load the Connection string I added into the "Settings > Configuration > Connection strings".

Here is the code I use to load it in my `Program.cs` file:

```
// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
```

The app works successfully when used locally w/ docker.

I tried to use Microsoft Key Store but it failed. Also tried to load connection string from env instead of configuration file. Last thing I have done is put into my `appsettings.json` a section `ConnectionStrings` with a `DefaultConnection` and an empty string to it, and that didn't work

Comment: could you clarify what Azure service do you use? App Service or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If you are deploying to Azure App Service there are basically two options to ship application settings:

1. make sure that your local `appsetting.json` is also copied to output directory (check file properties)
2. you can setup application settings including Connection Strings in App Settings tab of you App Service instance

Comment: i feel like that the appsettings.json file is well copied to the output directory because when i set the DefaultConnection value in this file the program starts, but is unable to connect since it's using the value of my local development database. However when i remove it the app just crashes. It kind of surprise me cause it feel like the Connection String i set is not overwriting properties of the appsettings.json file !

Comment: I have the same issue, while 2 should be working, it seems to return null. A workaround I am using now is defining ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection in Azure's regular application settings. But I'd like to know why setting a connection string isn't working.